# How to call REST Api in Xamarin.forms Portable app in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, rest, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am trying to connect a `Xamarin.Forms` portable app using REST service. I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition.

Rest Service is published locally which is running fine by url.
When I am trying to call my Rest service in application. It is throwing an exception:

> {System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException} with "One or more errors occurred."

C# Code at `ServiceWrapper.cs`:

```
public async Task<string> GetData()
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://ipaddress/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var response = client.GetAsync("IRESTApi.svc/xml/12").Result;
                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return content;
                //using (var client = new HttpClient())
                //{
                //    var result = await client.GetAsync("http://ipaddress/IRESTApi.svc/xml/12");
                //    return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //}
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var t = ex.Message;
                return t;
            }
        }
```

I am trying above method using [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/xamarin-working-rest-services-from-portable-class-andrei-dragotoniu) reference in android device. Please help.

Comment: Can you check the inner exception? It says there are multiple errors, there should be some details somewhere :) Also is this error on Android, iOS?

Comment: As a side note, you should replace this `client.GetAsync("IRESTApi.svc/xml/12").Result` with this `await client.GetAsync("IRESTApi.svc/xml/12")` . Use `await` whenever you can and  I can't find any reason not to use it in your context.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I have mentioned it for android device. and innerexception is "{System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException}".

Comment: That is the type of the inner exception. Please update your question with the messages of all the inner exceptions (an inner exception can have another inner exception)

Comment: @user3185569 Not working :( it is throwing `frame not in module` error.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis InnerException Count is only 1 that I have already mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :D

```
  public interface IGetData
  {
       Task<string> GetApiData();
  }

  public class GetData : IGetData
  {

    public async Task<string> GetApiData()
    {
      var client = new HttpClient();
      var response = await client.GetAsync(string.Format("http://mysite/api/Data"));
      var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      return responseString; 
    }

   }
```

Comment: I have already tried this code in my question. its showing 'frame not in module' error.